# Why are previous entries removed from my history if I visit them again later on?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, history

I've noticed with Google Chrome history that if I click on a link to a site I'd previously visited from the history or if I input the same URL in my address bar and go to it, it bumps the entry to the top of my history, but removes it as an entry from that first time I visited. Even if I go back to it later in the day.

If I check my history, sites I know I've visited at a certain time are missing as entries and then appear to be replaced with a vertical line as if I've not performed those visits.

Plus, it's odd because it will do this with some sites and not with others. Some I've clicked later in the day and they remain as an entry for when I visited previously.

For example, where my history went like so.....

12.00 PM    Google Chrome
11.30 PM    Google
11:00 PM    Google Hangouts
10.30 PM    Google Play

It now reads like this.....

7.05 PM     Google Hangouts
7.00 PM     Google
     |
12.00 PM    Google Chrome
     |
10.30 PM    Google Play

It's taken out the entries and bumped them to the new time I visited. I want to know if there is a way I can see my full history showing every single entry I've made including the first time I visited the site like in the first example above.

I've tried Better History, History 2, they don't help at all.....the entries still don't appear.

Sorry this post is long, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Yup.  Annoying.  Firefox does the same thing.  As for the effect of it happening on some and not others, it's been my experience that if you compare the full URLs between the old history item and the new history item that there are nuances after the initial `domain/page` that make them different (ie. `...domain/page?timestamp=...&google_referred....`)